# 5G System-Level Simulation results interpretation: BLER = 1 vs non-null goodput/throughput

Tags: matlab, performance, spectral-efficiency

I am simulating one UE at 10 km from gNB using 5G System-Level Simulator from Matlab. The BW = 20 MHz, and UE EIRP = 23 dB and channel is CDL-A (NLOS) / CDL-D (LOS), with a delay spread of 260 ns...
I am getting some throughput and goodput even when BLER is 1 (see the results below).
Is this correct? either yes or no, can you please explain why? Is this related to HARQ?

Also given the 3GPP target of 10% BLER, should I still consider performance values for BLERs > 10%?

*Results:*
"Peak UL Throughput: 131.89 Mbps. Achieved Cell UL Throughput: 65.53 Mbps

```
Achieved UL Throughput for each UE: [65.53]
Achieved Cell UL Goodput: 16.77 Mbps
Achieved UL Goodput for each UE: [16.77]
Peak UL spectral efficiency: 6.59 bits/s/Hz. Achieved UL spectral efficiency for cell: 0.84 bits/s/Hz 
Block error rate for each UE in the uplink direction: [1]."
```

Answer (score 0):

A block error rate of 1 is not compatible with non-zero goodput.

Goodput is defined to be the useful data rate, i.e. that which remains after all broken blocks have been discarded.

A BLER of 1 says all blocks are broken.

So, you wouldn't consider this result further, but need to dig further into how your specific simulation calculates this - something must be wrong.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Thanks a lot for your response. Exactly, I found this strange and this is why I was asking. I didn't touch anything from Matlab 5G simulator functions, i only set general parameters (Tx EIRP, UE position, BW...). In other words, I didn't interfere with simulator functions. Also, I doubt that these functions have something wrong, because they are developed by Matlab, i will try to see how it works...How about my second question when BLER > 10%?

Comment: well, you have to assume something is wrong. I don't care about whether it's from Mathworks or not – Matlab has been the basis for more than one wrong result. We might be misinterpreting the words "BLER" or "Goodput", or the simulation might be wrong. In all cases, **you must dig further how your specific simulation calculates this**. Thinking about whether > 10% is sensible is irrelevant at this point. Dig deeper.

Comment: Clear Marcus, thanks again for your response.